# Окно оплаты при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть свой лендинг (верстка, натянутая на вордпресс с помощью ACF), на котором есть всего три товара (меняться не будут). Для каждого есть кнпока 'купить'. Нужно, чтобы появлялось своё окно оплаты (можно и отдельную страницу), для каждого из товаров, без создания целого отдельного магазина с корзиной и прочим через WooCommerce. После этого Thank you page.

Я настроил уже оплату через api (была выбрана оплата через платежную систему mono), вопрос, как сделать, чтобы всплывало окно оплаты именно по нажатии на конкретную кнопку?

Как это реализовать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Уберите "Окно WooComerce оплаты" из заголовка, так как Вы не используете WooCommerce, при чем здесь тогда WooCommerce? Это вводит в заблуждение. Как сейчас работает Ваша оплата при помощи API и что значит: "Я настроил уже оплату через api"?

Comment: Не нужно удалять вопросы, нужно было добавить. И твой "лединг" тут не нужен. (И вообще это больше не вопрос, а задание)